# can't access ubuntu on my PC

Tags: 12.04

someone was trying to help me about a year ago. When I try to input my password the computer switches to the terminal window. They suggested that I download a new version of ubuntu and install it in my pc. I don't know how to initialize a disc to download and run a new version of ubuntu. can someone walk me through the process?

Answer (score 0):

just follow these points and you should have a successful installation of Ubuntu in no time!

**Step 1**

Download the iso file. To install Ubuntu, one needs the iso files, please go to this [link](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop). The downloads page shall have two options, to download 12.04 which is the latest LTS version of Ubuntu or 13.10 which was released last month. For the sake of this question, I suggest you download the LTS version, i.e 12.04.

**Step 2**

Make a bootable USB. The easiest way to install Ubuntu is via the bootable USB option. Now, I assume that you're on Windows so go this [link](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) and download the Windows version of Unetbootin.

**Step 3**

Now, our real work would start.

1. Open Unetbootin
2. Under the option for image files choose the iso file that you've downloaded
3. Under the option of choosing the drive where it would be installed choose your USB drive. **Please be careful, choose only your USB drive**
4. Let Unetbootin make the Bootable USB now.
5. Once that is done, reboot your machine and enter the `Boot Order Menu`. Here, choose your USB drive.
6. Now,  in a few minutes you should be able to boot into Ubuntu, but, we haven't installed Ubuntu yet, you're merely trying it out.
7. On your Ubuntu Desktop you should be able to see an option called **Install Ubuntu**.Choose that option and the loader shall start working.
8. Depending on your choice, you may choose to `Install Ubuntu and Replace Everything else` or `Install it alongside Windows` or `A custom Setup`, choose whichever one suits you best.
9. Let the installer do it's magic and soon enough, you'll have a successful installation of Ubuntu upon rebooting.